# How to make a conditional statement that will one of a couple of public constants to my email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to make a vba coded spreadsheet that will pull the information for the email of the person depending on if a cell has a certain value. Please if anyone can help show me what I am doing wrong that would be lovely. Thank you. Please understand that I have changed the passwords and people's email addresses to keep from letting there information get out. Thank you

```
Public Const TYemail As String = "Email Address"
Public Const AWemail As String = "Email Address"
Public Const MMemail As String = "Email Address"
Public Const DRemail As String = "Email Address"
Public Const MNemail As String = "Email Address"


Sub DoStuff()

    'Workbooks("Reoair or Rework Process Request.xlsm").Activate

    'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PM Sheet").Select
    'Range("C9").Value = "Sent to Eng - "
    'Range("D30").Value = RequestNo

    path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .TO = programemail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Repair or Rework Request"
        .htmlBody = "Repair request has been written for " & PN & " " & WO & " See: " & "<a href=""" & path & """>Here</a>"
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        '.Send
        'or use
        .Display
        '.send
    End With


    'End If

    ' Sheets("Page 1").Select
    ' ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
    ' Range     ("F36:G36,D10:J10,D11:J11,D12:J13,D14:J14,D15:J15,A18:J35,B36:D36,F36:G36" _
    '     ).Select
    '  Selection.Locked = False
    '  Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    '  Sheets("Page 1").Select
    '   ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"

    '  Sheets("Page 2(If Nec)").Select
    '  ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
    '  Range      ("F36:G36,D10:J10,D11:J11,D12:J13,D14:J14,D15:J15,A18:J35,B36:D36,F36:G36" _
    '     ).Select
    '  Selection.Locked = False
    '  Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    '   Sheets("Page 2(If Nec)").Select
    '   ActiveSheet.Protect "Password"

    '  Sheets("Page 1").Select


    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2, V2, AC2, H6, H8, H10, H14, H14").Locked = True

    Sheets("QE Sheet").Range("C10").value = Date


    ' Call DisableButtons


    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "Password"

    Sheets("QE Sheet").Protect "Password"
    Sheets("QE Sheet").Visible = xlHidden


    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Then I was trying to call from another sub I made to determine who gets the email

```
Sub EmailProgramManager()


    Sheets("PM Sheet").Unprotect "eng8246"


    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = MNemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = TYemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").Value = This Person" Then

        Set programemail = AWemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = MMemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = TYemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then


    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = MMemail

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").value = "This Person" Then

        Set programemail = MMemail

    End If


    'Sheets("PM Sheet").Protect "Password"

End Sub
```

Comment: just right off the bat, copying and pasting this into my IDE i found that there is a typo in `ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V6").Value = This Person" Then
        Set programemail = AWemail`. There should be starting quotes for `"This Person"``

Comment: But reading through it I imagine that's just caused by you updating it for anonymity. Let me instead recommend the `Select Case` Statement below

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would replace the `EmailProgramManager` sub that you created. It's easier to read and slightly faster even since it's not repeatedly calling the cell for its value :) It's also not necessary to unprotect a workbook just to get the value of a cell in it, so I removed that bit you had.

```
Sub EmailProgramManager()

    Select Case Sheets("PM Sheet").Range("V6").Value2
        Case "person 1"
            Set ProgramEmail = MNemail
        Case "person 2"
            Set ProgramEmail = TYemail

        '... more cases ...

        Case Else
            Set ProgramEmail = ""
    End Select

End Sub
```

---

Really, though, I would probably rethink the way that you work with this whole set of functions. I don't think the email address setter should really be messing around with globals but should instead be passed a range containing the program manager, and then just return their email address as a string.

Here's just a quick example of how you might change both of these to make this work more logically:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoStuff()

    '... preceding code ...

    Dim i
    For i = 4 To 6  'based on the range used to decide how many emails to send

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = EmailProgramManager(Range("V" & i))
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Repair or Rework Request"
            .htmlBody = "Repair request has been written for " & PN & " " & WO & " See: " & "<a href=""" & path & """>Here</a>"
            .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing

    Next i

    '... following code

End Sub

Function EmailProgramManager(ByVal rng As Range) As String

    Select Case Sheets("PM Sheet").rng.Value2
        Case "person 1"
            EmailProgramManager = "email 1"
        Case "person 2"
            EmailProgramManager = "email 2"

        '... more cases ...

        Case Else
            EmailProgramManager = ""
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Okay, So then how would I call this to the email? would using the EmailProgramManager work for who the email is supposed to go to?

Comment: Now it's telling me that the argument is not optional

Comment: @Stacie right, to use the second one you'll have to make some changes to the `DoStuff` subroutine as well. I'm working on an edit to show you how you'd go about it.

Comment: @Stacie okay, here's my attempt to adapt what you had to a different approach so that it can generate multiple emails at once based on, for example, `V4:V6`. It might not perfectly work for you because visualizing your data is kind of difficult, but I still thought it was worth including

Comment: Just to give you an understanding, I am taking this sheet, Pressing a button will send one email to the correct person depending on who is involved.

Comment: How does it pick which cell to look at. Is it always going to be looking at cell `V6` like the example given in your code above?

Comment: Yes it is, However, I took the entire code that is going to be in the outlook section and threw them in different If statements. Doing that I was able to just use the public constant. so,     If "This Person" Then outlook all of the code, Send: "This person's email" If that makes sense